# ESLint spaces arguments of the function with additional padding when on new line

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to figure out which ESLint rule changes spacing in function call's arguments but with no luck (I'm using google recommended rules).

From this:

```js
Object.assign(
  {
    a: "b"
  },
  {
    b: "a"
  }
);
```

To:

```js
Object.assign(
    {
      a: "b"
    },
    {
      b: "a"
    }
);
```

It happens on all function calls containing each argument in new line.

Comment: I'm not familiar with eslint, but I think you mean [indent](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/indent)?

Comment: This isn't your fault but it's a pet peeve of mine: don't use a *linting* tool to do code *formatting*. There's a difference between usage patterns that are code smells (e.g. unused Promises, unused function parameters, assignment in an `if` condition, etc) that are the domain of linters and ones that are just matters of taste which would be the formatter's job. Use eslint for linting and something like [prettier](https://prettier.io/) for formatting.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I've given a closer look the `indent` and it was it! The `CallExpression` argument was set to `2` and I've changed it to `first` which fixed it. Do you mind changing your comment into an answer, so I can mark it as "answered"?

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm not a fan of having separate tools for each need when I can work a little and have only one. Also having to synchronize my analizing tool to not report my prettier tool changes as errors is another level of bliss, thank you for your suggestion, but I will stick with eslint.